# Is there a single word as a substitute for "make .. constant"?

Tags: phrases

> This method makes the pressure in a container when the temperature in
>   the container is less than 10℃ constant.

This is just an example I created.  In this example, the words "make" and "constant" are away from each other. Is it possible to rewrite this in such a manner that "This method makes constant the pressure..."? or is there a single word  as a substitute for "make .. constant"?

Comment: I think there are several or even numerous ways to say that. My suggestion: "Under this method the pressure in the (a?) container remains unchanged for the temperatures lower than 10 C."

Comment: The pressure in the container is made constant by [some action]. No, there is not one word for the idea of to make something constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is grammatical to bring the word **constant** to the front of the sentence in that situation so that it comes after **makes**:

> This method makes constant the pressure in a container when its
>   internal temperature is less than 10℃.

or to place it after **container**:

> This method makes the pressure in a container constant when its
>   internal temperature is less than 10℃.

Compare:

> He wished to make known a feature of so-called "small
>   clauses".
>
> He wished to make a feature of so-called "small
>   clauses" known.

P.S. You can also substitute the verb **keep** for the verb **make** as user Gustavson says in his answer.  I think **keep** is better here than **make**.

Comment: I think keeping "make" and the adjective or participle together will be more usual -- and correct -- when in the presence of a long direct object. Thus, "make the rules known" (where the DO object is short) is better than "make known the rules", don't you agree?

Comment: Yes, I would agree that caboose position is suboptimal with a long intervening object.   I think it's ultimately as stylistic choice, however, and can imagine circumstances where even with a short object it might be desirable to say "make known those rules".

Comment: "Hold" constant would be another alternative to make or keep..

Answer (score 2):

A possible one-word synonym for "make (sth) constant" is "stabilize". However, "stabilize" suggests that the thing being stabilized (in this case, the pressure) was unstable, which might not always be the case.

Your sentence could be improved if you extraposed what does not need to remain in mid position:

- This method makes/keeps the pressure in a container constant when its temperature / when the temperature inside is less/lower than 10ºC.

I think "keep sth constant" makes more sense that "make sth constant". Otherwise, if the condition was not constant and becomes constant by applying a method, "stabilize" could be a more appropriate choice.

Answer (score 2):

What about **fix**?

> This method **fixes** the pressure in a container when the temperature in the container is less than 10℃.

Answer (score 1):

What about "[stabilizes](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/stabilize)"?

> to cause something to become fixed and stop changing, esp. in order to keep it from becoming worse, or to become fixed and stop changing:
>   ***These medicines stabilize your heart rate and lower blood pressure.***

So, in your sentence,

> This method stabilizes the pressure in a container when the internal temperature is less than 10℃.

If the implication is that the pressure is otherwise yoyoing up and down, this should work quite well for you.

Alternately, you could rearrange your sentence slightly to avoid repeating words and bring "make" and "constant" closer together:

> This method makes the pressure in a container constant when the internal temperature is less than 10℃.

This doesn't require a new term, instead cleaning up the text.

Answer (score 1):

Opposing constant forces meet at a point called an *equilibrium.*  The single-word verb form of this is *equilibrate*.

> This method equilibrates the pressure in a container, when the temperature in the container is less than 10℃.